# How to average the 2-d arrays with nan values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, python-2.x

I have 12 .grd files saved in the same path all in the format of 2-d array.

For averaging their values, I used the simple loop method

```
ave_value = np.zeros_like(test_array) # generate a zero-array firstly
for i in range(0,12,1):
    file_path = %(i+1)+'.grd' #1.grd, 2.grd,...
    # read_grd is an user-defined function
    value, nodata_value = read_grd(file_path)
    value[value == nodata_value] = np.nan    
    ave_value_+=value
ave_value = ave_value/12.0
```

However, I found this fuction failed to consider the location contains some np.nan values.

For example, position [2,2] in one grid file was np.nan, but have certain values in other datasets. However, in the above averaging process, the average value in the derived  *ave-value* is also np.nan.

Is there any better solution to average different 2-d array concerning the np.nan value, i.e., if the values of a specific position is np.nan in 3 files, we only average the corresponding values in other 9 files.

Any advices or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.nanmean()`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html

```
a = np.array([np.nan, 3.4, 5.2, np.nan, 1.2])
b = np.nanmean(a)
print(b)

>>> 3.266666666667
```

For 2D arrays (or n-dimensional arrays), you can play with the `axis` keyword to specify how you want to calculate the mean.